# Create a downloadable archive on Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

If I have a project on Gitlab and want to provide a downloadable archive, but that archive should only contain the content of the local `build` directory (that directory is in the `.gitignore` so it is not committed), how would I do that?

I have read about the [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) command but I don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: You could make a 'Release' and attach the file there

Comment: @Moray thank you, but comments aren't meant to give partial answers.

Comment: @Moray release are based on tag or ref so the files must be committed before creating the release

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I understand your question properly, but I think what you are looking for are [GitLab artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html). I'm making an assumption here, and that is that you are trying to upload a `build` folder that is generated as the result of a build of the project.

If you use GitLab CICD to build your project (define the build in the file `.gitlab-ci.yml`, you can upload artifacts to GitLab that are created as a result of the build process.

When you trigger a pipeline, you must have a runner available to pick up the pipeline.

In order to be able to access files that are available on the machine on which your GitLab runner runs, specify which files should be uploaded to GitLab using the syntax for artifacts. For instance, if you wished to upload a folder located at project/build, specify:

```yaml
  #put the following at the end of the stage in which the project/build folder is generated.
  artifacts:
      paths:
        - project/build/
      expire_in: 1 week #set to never to never expire
```

You can keep files for longer than 1 week, see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#browsing-artifacts) and [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifactsexpire_in)

Comment: This is a good start, I will take a look at it. Thank you!